# Is there a definitive or idiots guide to implementing strong web security using ASP.Net MVC 2/SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, security

I'm about to begin building an e-commerce website using c#, ASP.Net MVC 2, IIS7 and SQL 2008.  The site will allow users to login, make purchases, and manage their orders.  Obviously, there's a need for strong security here.  I've been searching around on SO and Google for a single definitive guide that covers enough on security to allow me to...

1. learn where security needs to be a consideration and...
2. how to implement it properly on the Windows stack.

This will be my first e-commerce site that I'm building from scratch.  Is there a definitive or idiots guide to implementing strong web security for all aspects of an e-commerce site using ASP.Net MVC 2/SQL 2008?

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Definitive" and "idiots guide" seem a little mutually exclusive, but here's a few I've seen before that deal with general ASP.NET security and some specifically for MVC:

[Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649100.aspx) (Microsoft, MSDN)

[Developer Highway Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/aa473878.aspx) (Security - MSDN - Microsoft UK)

[Improving Web Application Security: Threats and Countermeasures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994921) (Microsoft, MSDN)

[The HaaHa Show: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Security with Haack and Hanselman](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT05) (Microsoft Video)

There's also some tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc/security about preventing javascript attacks. Basically this boils down to **always** HTML encoding any output.

As for SQL 2008, normal best practice would be to use Windows Authentication and only grant read/write access to the tables you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the MVC Security page on [ASP.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/security).

They have a few good videos and their sample applications have been helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Start with OWASP.

OWASP is the authority on Web Application Security.  Their list of top ten vulnerabilities is the bible for web security.

Try here for OWASP overview: http://www.owasp.org

And here for the OWASP top ten: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

The latter link shows how to protect against these threats including .Net code.